# How to serialize RapidJSON document to a string?

Tags: c++, string, document, rapidjson

How to serialize RapidJSON document to a string?
In all the examples the serializing text is redirected to the standard output through the `FileStream`, but I need to redirect it to a string variable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like this:

```
const char *GetJsonText()
{
  rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;

  buffer.Clear();

  rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
  doc.Accept(writer);

  return strdup( buffer.GetString() );
}
```

Then of couse you have to call free() on the return, or do:

```
return string( buffer.GetString() );
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks... but the line "doc.Accept(writer);" it returns "null" value. I don't understand the reason.????? when I do "doc['x'].Accept(writer);" It returns the value of x. why the null value....? :(

Comment: You will have to post some example code, I can't tell you by just guessing.

Comment: I just had a quick look. Accept returns a bool. It can't return NULL. I consider doc to be of type rapidjson::Document, initialized with doc.Parse( jsonDaten.c_str() );.

Comment: Does this work for nested rapidjson documents as well?

Comment: I have a question, may be a stupid question, what is the object type of `buffer.GetString()`

Answer (score 19):

In the [first page of the project](http://rapidjson.org/), the code already shows how to serialize a document into a string (stringify a document):

```
// 3. Stringify the DOM
StringBuffer buffer;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
d.Accept(writer);

// Output {"project":"rapidjson","stars":11}
std::cout << buffer.GetString() << std::endl;
```

`buffer.GetString()` here returns a string of `const char*` type. It also has a `buffer.GetSize()` for returning the size of output string. So, if you would convert it to a `std::string`, the best way is:

```
std::string s(buffer.GetString(), buffer.GetSize());
```

The [tutorial.cpp](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/master/example/tutorial/tutorial.cpp) also show the same thing, in addition to other common usage of RapidJSON.

Comment: Will the destructor of `buffer` free the `buffer.GetString()` ? If yes, then is there a way to *move* the content of `buffer` rather than *copy* it?

Answer (score 4):

Example code:

```
Document document;
const char *json = " { \"x\" : \"0.01\", \"y\" :\"0.02\" , \"z\" : \"0.03\"} ";

document.Parse<0>(json);

//convert document to string

StringBuffer strbuf;
strbuf.Clear();

Writer<StringBuffer> writer(strbuf);
document.Accept(writer);

std::string ownShipRadarString = strbuf.GetString();
std::cout << "**********************************************" << ownShipRadarString << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having to copy out the string contents, you can create a rapidjson Stream-concept class to wrap an existing std::string, ref: https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/issues/846#issuecomment-298088278

In fact, not all the methods implemented there are required. This should do:

```
void writeDocumentToString(const rapidjson::Document& document,
                           std::string& output)
{
  class StringHolder
  {
  public:
    typedef char Ch;
    StringHolder(std::string& s) : s_(s) { s_.reserve(4096); }
    void Put(char c) { s_.push_back(c); }
    void Flush() { return; }

  private:
    std::string& s_;
  };

  StringHolder os(output);
  rapidjson::Writer<StringHolder> writer(os);
  document.Accept(writer);
}
```